# child nodes of treeview node

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have an xml file with following structure:

```
<table name="tblcats">
    <row>
        <Id>3680</Id>
        <Industry>Associations</Industry>
        <ParentId>1810</ParentId>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Id>1592</Id>
        <Industry>Fortune 100</Industry>
        <ParentId>1810</ParentId>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Id>1601</Id>
        <Industry>Oil &amp; Gas Operations</Industry>
        <ParentId>1689</ParentId>
    </row>
    <row>
</table>
```

I want to create a treeview using this XML file. I have written following code

```
   ' Load a TreeView control from an XML file.
    Private Sub LoadTreeViewFromXmlFile(ByVal file_name As String, ByVal trv As TreeView)
        ' Load the XML document.
        Dim xml_doc As New XmlDocument
        xml_doc.Load(file_name)

        ' Add the root node's children to the TreeView.
        trv.Nodes.Clear()
        trv.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(xml_doc.DocumentElement.Name))
        AddTreeViewChildNodes(trv.Nodes, xml_doc.DocumentElement)
    End Sub

    ' Add the children of this XML node 
    ' to this child nodes collection.
    Private Sub AddTreeViewChildNodes(ByVal parent_nodes As TreeNodeCollection, ByVal xml_node As XmlNode)
        For Each child_node As XmlNode In xml_node.ChildNodes
            ' Make the new TreeView node.
            Dim new_node As TreeNode = New TreeNode(child_node.Item("Industry").InnerText, child_node.Item("Id").InnerText)

            parent_nodes.Add(new_node)

        Next child_node
    End Sub
```

but it creates a treeview like this:

```
->table
->Associations
->Fortune 100
```

where as I want table as parent element like this

```
->table
  ->Associations
  ->Fortune 100
```

so that If i click table node, all tree collapses or expands. Please suggest how can i fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are passing the tree view control itself into the AddTreeViewChildNodes method, so it is adding all the nodes at that same top level.  You need to pass the root node that you created into the method so it adds the children under it.

Change:

```
    trv.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode(xml_doc.DocumentElement.Name))
    AddTreeViewChildNodes(trv.Nodes, xml_doc.DocumentElement)
```

To:

```
    Dim rootNode As TreeNode = New TreeNode(xml_doc.DocumentElement.Name)
    trv.Nodes.Add(rootNode)
    AddTreeViewChildNodes(rootNode, xml_doc.DocumentElement)
```